# Remove "add new customer" button in ui component grid with condition base?

Tags: magento2, customer, grid, uicomponent, custom-button

I want to remove the "add new customer" button in condition base. 
"add new customer" button only display for main admin, not any child admin.

[image]

any have an idea about the same problem.
Thank you in advance

Comment: @Amit Bera ji, This is not a duplicate question. I want to remove button with condition base would you please reopen the same question?

Comment: hi i have posted solutions please accept and upvote if you found this answer helpful

Answer (score 1):

You need to update layout handle base on condion to achieve this

Create **Test\Module\etc\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="load_custom_handler" instance="Test\Module\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create **Test\Module\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Module\Observer;

class LayoutLoadBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_authSession;

    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
    ) 
    {
        $this->_authSession = $authSession;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        if($this->_authSession->isLoggedIn() && $this->_authSession->getUser()->getRole()->getRoleName() == 'Your Role Name')
        {
            $layout = $observer->getLayout();   
            $layoutHandler = $layout->getUpdate()->getHandles();

            if(in_array('customer_index_index', $layoutHandler))
            {
                $layout->getUpdate()->removeHandle('customer_index_index');
                $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customer_index_index_custom'); 
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Create **Test\Module\view\adminhtml\layout\customer_index_index_custom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="formkey"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="customer_listing_custom"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create **Test\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\customer_listing_custom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing_custom.customer_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <spinner>customer_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>customer_listing_custom.customer_listing_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="customer_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
        <settings>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        </settings>
        <aclResource>Magento_Customer::manage</aclResource>
        <dataProvider class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider" name="customer_listing_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <exportButton name="export_button"/>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="customer/index/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</param>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing_custom.customer_listing_custom.customer_columns.ids</param>
            </editorConfig>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing_custom.customer_listing_custom.customer_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids" sortOrder="10">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="entity_id" sortOrder="20">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="name" sortOrder="30">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Name</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="email" sortOrder="40">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Email</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="group_id" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="50">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Group</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_telephone" sortOrder="60">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Phone</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_postcode" sortOrder="70">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">ZIP</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_country_id" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="80">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Country</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_region" sortOrder="90">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">State/Province</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date" sortOrder="100">
            <settings>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Customer Since</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="website_id" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Websites" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="110">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Web Site</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="confirmation" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Confirmation" sortOrder="130">
            <settings>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Confirmed email</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="created_in" sortOrder="140">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Account Created in</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_full" sortOrder="150">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Billing Address</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="shipping_full" sortOrder="160">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Shipping Address</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="dob" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date" sortOrder="170">
            <settings>
                <timezone>false</timezone>
                <dateFormat>MMM d, y</dateFormat>
                <skipTimeZoneConversion>true</skipTimeZoneConversion>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Date of Birth</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="taxvat" sortOrder="180">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Tax VAT Number</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="gender" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="190">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Gender</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_street" sortOrder="200">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Street Address</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_city" sortOrder="210">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">City</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_fax" sortOrder="220">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Fax</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_vat_id" sortOrder="230">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">VAT Number</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_company" sortOrder="240">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Company</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_firstname" sortOrder="250">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Billing Firstname</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_lastname" sortOrder="260">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Billing Lastname</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="lock_expires" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\AccountLock" sortOrder="270">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Account Lock</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Actions">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```