# Change page layout dynamically depending on url parameter

Tags: magento2, page-layouts, edit, dynamic

The standard layout of my categories is 2-columns-left so that the layered navigation is visible in my shop. What I want is, to use the same categories to display content.

This is an example for my shop link:
**products/chemicals.html**
If I click this link my products are shown in my list.phtml

This is an example for my "cms" link:
**products/chemicals.html?cms_id=123**
If I click this link my "cms" content is displayed in my list.phtml

What I want now, is to display my content without the left sidebar.
By CSS I can set the sidebar display:none, that works, but the page loads my products.

I would prefer to change the page layout when I call my "cms" category page.

Any idea?

Christian

Comment: check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/277066/66058

Answer (score 0):

Create a frontend/events.xml

```
<event name="layout_load_before">
    <observer name="test_layout_change" instance="Tets\Module\Observer\AddUpdateHandlesObserver" />
</event>
```

Create class for Observer.

```
<?php
namespace Test\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

/**
 * Class AddUpdateHandlesObserver
 * @package Test\Module\Observer
 */
class AddUpdateHandlesObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

/**
 * @var Http
 */
protected $request;

/**
 * @var StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;

/**
 * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $productRepository;


/**
 * AddUpdateHandlesObserver constructor.
 * @param Http                       $request           Request
 * @param StoreManagerInterface      $storeManager      StoreManager
 * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository ProductRepository
 */
public function __construct(
    Http $request,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->request           = $request;
    $this->storeManager      = $storeManager;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}//end __construct()


/**
 * @param Observer $observer Observer
 * @return $this|bool|void
 */
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $layout         = $observer->getData('layout');

    if ({ur_conditon}) {


        $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('layout_file_name');
    }

    return $this;
}//end execute()


}//end class
```

Create `layout_file_name.xml`
Inside extend the parent_layout file and remove the respective sidebar from the xml file.

```
<update handle="catalog_category_view" />
<body>
<referenceBlock name="block_name_which_you_want_remove" remove="true" />
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have not been here since a long time.